# SQL Server error handling in cursor inside trigger

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, triggers, cursor

I'm new to SQL Server error handling, and my English isn't too clear, so I apologize in advance for any misuderstandings.

The problem is: I insert multiple records into a table. The table has an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, which is processing the records one by one in the FETCH WHILE cycle with a cursor. If something error happens, everything is rolling back. So if there is just one wrong field in the inserted records, I lost all of them. And the insert rolls back also, so I can't find the wrong record. So I need to handle the errors inside of the cursor, to rollback only the wrong record.

I made a test database with 3 tables:

**tA**

```
VarSmallint smallint
VarTinyint tinyint
String varchar(20)
```

**tB**

```
ID int (PK, identity)
Timestamp datetime (default: getdate())
VarSmallint smallint
VarTinyint tinyint
String varchar(20)
```

**tC**

```
ID int PK
Timestamp datetime
VarTinyint1 tinyint
VarTinyint2 tinyint
String varchar(10)
```

`tA` contains 3 records with 1 wrong one. I insert this content into `tB`.
`tB` has the trigger, and inserts the records into `tC` ony by one.

`tC` has only tinyint variables, so there can be problem to insert values greater than 255. This is the point where the error occurs for the test!

My trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_tB] 
ON  [dbo].[tB] 
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF @@rowcount = 0
        RETURN;

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
         @ID                AS int,
         @Timestamp     AS datetime,
         @VarSmallint   AS smallint,
         @VarTinyint        AS tinyint,
         @String            AS varchar(20),

    DECLARE curNyers CURSOR DYNAMIC
    FOR
        SELECT
            [ID], [Timestamp], [VarSmallint], [VarTinyint], [String]
        FROM INSERTED
        ORDER BY [ID]

    OPEN curNyers

    FETCH NEXT FROM curNyers INTO @ID, @Timestamp, @VarSmallint, @VarTinyint, @String

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tC]([ID], [Timestamp], [VarTinyint1], [VarTinyint2], [String])
        VALUES (@ID, @Timestamp, @VarSmallint, @VarTinyint, @String)

        COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tErrorLog]([ErrorTime], [UserName], [ErrorNumber],
                                      [ErrorSeverity], [ErrorState],
                                      [ErrorProcedure], [ErrorLine],
                                      [ErrorMessage], [RecordID])
        VALUES (SYSDATETIME(), SUSER_NAME(), ERROR_NUMBER(),
                ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(),
                ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_LINE(),
                ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ID)

        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM curNyers INTO @ID, @Timestamp, @VarSmallint, @VarTinyint, @String
    END

    CLOSE curNyers
    DEALLOCATE curNyers
END
```

If I insert 2 good records with 1 wrong, everything is rolling back and I got an error:

> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Please help me! How to modify this trigger to work well?

If I insert the wrong record, I need:

1. All the inserted records in tB
2. All the good records in tC
3. Error logged in tErrorLog

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the `TRIGGER`, and copy-pasted the code from it into a `STORED PROCEDURE`.

Then I added a row `Status` to tB, and set defaults to 0.

1 is "Record processed OK", 2 is "Record processing fault".

I fill the cursor with `WHERE Status = 0`.

In the `TRY` section I update the status to 1, in the `CATCH` section I `UPDATE` it to 2.

I have no jobs, so I run the SP from Windows scheduler with a batch file with the `SQLCMD` command.

Now the processing works well, moreover it worked well for the first time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have **TWO major disasters** in your trigger:

1. do not use a **cursor** inside a trigger - that's just horrible! Triggers fire whenever a given operation happens - you have little control over when and how many times they fire. Therefore, in order not to compromise your system performance too much, triggers should be very **small, fast, nimble** - do **not** do any heavy lifting and extensive processing in a trigger. A cursor is **anything but** nimble and fast - it's a resource-hog, processor-hog, memory-leaking monster - **AVOID** those whenever you can, and most definitely inside a trigger! (and you don't need them, 99% of the cases, anyway)

   You can rewrite your whole logic into this one single, fast, set-based statement:

   ```
   ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_tB] 
   ON [dbo].[tB] 
   AFTER INSERT
   AS 
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[tC]([ID], [Timestamp], [VarTinyint1], [VarTinyint2], [String])
           SELECT
               [ID], [Timestamp], [VarSmallint], [VarTinyint], [String]
           FROM 
               INSERTED
   END
   ```
2. Never call `COMMIT TRAN` inside a trigger. The trigger executes inside the context and transaction of the statement that caused it to fire - if everything is OK, just let the trigger finish and then the transaction will be committed just fine. If you need to abort, call `ROLLBACK`. But **never ever** call `COMMIT TRAN` in the middle of a trigger. Just don't.....